# REACT: Is it possible to upgrade older projects to the latest version of React 18?

Tags: reactjs, upgrade

I am confused. I am working on a project that is written on an older React version 15.6.2. I am adding new features and I do some maintenance.

Is it possible to upgrade these older projects to the latest version of React 18?

Very often I heard people talking about working on an older version of React.  They talked about having to use the old CLASS components etc. So I assumed that it was not possible to update to the latest version.

But just now I came across a few videos and articles, in which people talked about upgrading older React projects to the latest React 18 version.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Update the package to whatever version you want to use, then fix any compiler issues and behavior changes if any (just like upgrading any older version of a library to a newer one). But that does not change class components to functional components, which needs to be done separately once you have a React version that supports them.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the project is very big. Upgrading to REACT 18 would mean that I would have to upgrade the code of the whole project. And that is a lot of work. Presently I need to rewrite one component only, we have some bugs there. The rest of the project works fine. –

Comment: And that is always a trade-off, especially if there has not been effort to upgrade sooner and minimize changes in each update. I've found that often, if you let things go for years, you could be locked into the old library/framework/language version as the upgrade process at that point might be too much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's still possible. Class components have been deprecated but not removed. You can still find them in the API documentation under the [Legacy](https://react.dev/reference/react/legacy) section.

However, normally when upgrading it's better to upgrade code as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the project is very big. Upgrading to REACT 18 would mean that I would have to upgrade the code of the whole project. And that is a lot of work. Presently I need to rewrite one component only, we have some bugs there. The rest of the project works fine.

Comment: @DaliborPavlik, well, I also strongly recommend to upgrade your code, but this is not possible, check this https://medium.com/welldone-software/two-ways-to-run-tests-on-different-versions-of-the-same-library-f-e-react-17-react-16-afb7f861d1e9

Comment: @DaliborPavlik Normally upgrading React is not a problem. The problem can be upgrading some dependent library, e.g. `react-router` that has to be upgraded together and introduces breaking changes.